# R : Combine categorical row values in a group to a single value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which is similar to structure to the one below.

| Name | Label |
| --- | --- |
| A | historical |
| A | comedy |
| B | tragedy |
| C | comedy |
| C | young adult |

I want to combine this into a dataframe, so what all labels with a common name appear in one row. The ideal output would look something like this.

| Name | Labels |
| --- | --- |
| A | "historical', "comedy" |
| B | "tragedy" |
| C | "comedy", "young adult" |

So far, I have tried grouping the data together, and then applying a function to the group using `group_map()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- data.frame(name = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'), 
                      labels = c('historical', 'comedy', 'tragedy', 'comedy', 'young adult'))

combined_label <- function(dt, ...) {
    print(dt[['labels']]) 
    dt['labels'] <- dt[['labels']]
    print(dt['labels']) 
    return(dt)}

test_df <- test_df %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    group_map(combined_label)
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to work. While dt[['labels']]` does give a factor of all the values (e.g. c('historical', 'comedy')), I seem to be having difficulty in combining them together. What I get as my output is:

```
A tibble: 2 × 1
labels
<fct>
crime
horror
A tibble: 2 × 1
labels
<fct>
comedy
historical
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want the column to be? just a single string? a vector of strings? a list of strings?

Comment: @bouncyball a vector of strings or a list of strings - I don't mind the format per se as I can convert between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr) 

d %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(Label1 = list(Label)) 

  Name  Label1   
  <chr> <list>   
1 A     <chr [2]>
2 B     <chr [1]>
3 C     <chr [2]>
```

And another way, using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Label ~ Name, data = d, FUN = c)

  Name               Label
1    A  historical, comedy
2    B             tragedy
3    C comedy, young adult
```

#### Data

```
d <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), 
                    Label = c("historical", "comedy", "tragedy", 
                              "comedy", "young adult")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why you use `row.names = c(NA, -5L)` and a structure to create the dataframe and how it helps? I modified my answer to show how I initialised the dataframe by simply calling data.frame(), and using list() inside summarise() returns some numbers.

Comment: The part at the bottom comes from the output of `dput`. Check to see if `Labels` in your data is a factor. If it is a factor, you should convert it to a character. You can either do this "by hand" or in specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your call to `data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` may also help here, if the output is not required as a `listcol`

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Label = toString(Label))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Name  Label              
  <chr> <chr>              
1 A     historical, comedy 
2 B     tragedy            
3 C     comedy, young adult
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Label ~ Name, d, FUN = toString)
```